# How can we use validation laravel in jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation

How can i use `validation` `laravel` with `jquery`

i try this with laravel validation

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'branch' => 'required|not_in:---Select Branch---',
            'dep' => 'required|not_in:--- Select Department ---',
            'txt_phone' => 'required|numeric|min:8',
            'txt_ext' => 'required|min:3|max:5' ], [
            'txt_phone.min' => 'Phone at least 9 characters',
            'txt_phone.max' => 'Phone not be greater than 10 characters',
            'txt_phone.numeric' => 'Phone must be nummeric']);
```

But it's `validate` in the `server` i want to `validate` it on `client` with `jquery` how can i??

Comment: Use Jquery Validation Plugin

Comment: @SagarGautam package from github??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Best way to validate form with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762376/laravel-5-best-way-to-validate-form-with-javascript)

Comment: @TheRock see here https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @RameshRajendran thank you very much

Comment: @SagarGautam Thnak you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can return

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return $validator->errors();
}
```

for your return ajax